# calling client side event on button click in GridView

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I need to call a javasript function when a button is clicked in my GridView.  Is it possible to do this, and if so does somebody have an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  <asp:TemplateField>
       <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="javascript:alert('hello');" />
   </asp:TemplateField>
```